# The category "Other" in my Storage takes 4GB out of 6GB on my Internal Storage, any way to clean it?

Tags: storage, htc, htc-one, htc-one-s

I have HTC One S. When I open my Storage , it says :
4.10GB/6.07GB ; 
Apps: 220MB ; Other : 3.88GB ; Available: 1.97GB .
That's after I restarted my phone on Backup & Reset. I did it several times , and it doesn't change. I'm clueless. I don't have any ideas on what could take that space , nor how do I clean it (properly ofc.). I was looking on the internet for a whole week, and still have found nothing useful. I have tried Clean Master. It doesn't make any difference in the "Other" category. Still the same. It is a old phone , my dad was using it for 1/1.5 years , but I don't think it has any influence on the current memory , after resetting the phone.

Only the "Apps" is clickable in Storage. In other words - I cant click on "Other" to see what's inside. I tried an app called "Disk Usage" , and it says: 1)When I click on app storage : Applications : 220MiB ; Data : 2236MiB ; Free space : 2016MiB . 
Now , 2)When I click on Storage card: Storage card: 10171MiB ; System data... Android... (and many more little stuff) ; Free space 10164MiB...

I'm not worried about my phone storage - on storage card. I'm worried about my internal storage , which is, I'm pretty sure , showed on app storage. The big thing : FREAKING 2236MiB FOR DATA? It has to be Data that's messing me up. Data is lost when resetting the phone with erasing al the data , right? I did it several times , but still , the category "Other" still doesn't change at all.

From this , kind of a bigger talk... well to read it is big, right? Never mind...
Again , from this bigger talk , I actually only want to know the answers for two questions : What is on "Other"? and , How do I clean "Other"

Thank you for responding in advance.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ABE64B8B54D4B3FA!3407&authkey=!AEzUeDYmxJnRCo8&ithint=folder%2c  (here are the pictures)

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)

Comment: I don't see where/how to put screenshots in a comment.

Comment: You can [edit] your question and upload your screenshots there.

Comment: I have added the link for the pictures. It should work , and if more pictures are needed , tell me.

Comment: @YouLiveOnlyTwice Do you see a `sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails` folder? If so, delete it.

Comment: Don't see it. Doesn't mean its probably not there , right? Nevermind. Just to mention : I can totally delete anything on my phone. If possible , I want to make it as clean as new. Not much stupid data taking over my internal storage...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the app data. For example, on my phone I see 184mb for Abbyy (that's dictionaries), and I'm 100% sure those 184 come of the downloaded dictionaries for the app.

To remove the data (I'm not responsible for the lost data in apps, because there will be such):

- click on any of the checkboxes before the data chunk name
- click select all in the top bar
- click the recycle bin in the top bar

Comment: I do not see what you mean. I am not really into this stuff. Can you go step by step with me? 1)Open settings ; 2)Apps .... and stuff like that , please

Comment: @You What? You know how to go to "other", right? So you go there and apply my steps.

Comment: The "Other" is not clickable..